# unable to call PSTN microsoft graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, postman

I get the following error when calling the PSTN api
[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403 wrong authorization it seems

Comment: used a new token still the error is same :/

Comment: 403 means you're authenticated but don't have access rights to call this api.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you have necessary permissions to call this API.

[image]

Refer to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-getpstncalls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Thanks.